# Formatting a table with multiple headers and some cells combined

Tags: tables

I tried to set up a table to track the effects of 4 treatments on some objectives to insert it into my dissertation. I tried to use examples I found them here, but I face difficulty and not working for my situation (maybe because I have a large table and some cells have combined rows).
This is what I want to set up: [image: Table]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! please show us the code you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do You want to have something like that?

```
\begin{table}[]
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{|l|}{Treatment 1} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Treatment 2} & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Treatment 3}                                  & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Treatment 4}                                \\ \hline
Obj\#      & RR      & Radius     & Obj\#          & RR   & Radius   & Obj\#                                               & RR & Radius & Obj\#                                             & RR & Radius \\ \hline
1          &         &            & 1              &      &          & 2                                                   &    &        & 2                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
2          &         &            & Dissapeared    & -    &          & 5                                                   &    &        & 4                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
3          &         &            & 2              &      &          & 4                                                   &    &        & 5                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
-          &         &            & 3              &      &          & 3                                                   &    &        & 6                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
-          &         &            & 4              &      &          & 1                                                   &    &        & 1                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
-          &         &            & 5              &      &          & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}6\\ \\ \\ 9\end{tabular} &    &        & \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}8\\ \\ 10\end{tabular} &    &        \\ \hline
-          &         &            & 6              &      &          & 7                                                   &    &        & 7                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
-          &         &            & 7              & 1    &          & 8                                                   &    &        & 9                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
-          & -       & -          & -              & -    & -        & -                                                   & -  & -      & 3                                                 &    &        \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, Thank you so much! I don't know I need to add a tabular inside the main one. I appreciate your replay.

Comment: You are welcome, also if you work with tables a lot, I would recommend  You to visit this site https://www.tablesgenerator.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use of the `tabularray` package. Using it the table code is shorter and result (too my opinion) nicer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec={*{12}{Q[l,m]}}
             }
\SetCell[c=3]{l} Treatment 1    &   &
    & \SetCell[c=3]{l} Treatment 2  &   &
        & \SetCell[c=3]{l} Treatment 3  &   &
            & \SetCell[c=3]{l} Treatment 4  &       \\
Obj\#   & RR     & Radius          
    & Obj\#   & RR     & Radius
        & Obj\#   & RR     & Radius 
            & Obj\#   & RR      & Radius            \\
1   &   &   & 1 &   &   & 2 &   &   & 2 &           \\
2   &   &   & {Dissa-\\peared}    
                & - &   & 5 &   &   & 4 &           \\
3   &   &   & 2 &   &   & 4 &   &   & 5 &           \\
-   &   &   & 3 &   &   & 3 &   &   & 6 &           \\
-   &   &   & 4 &   &   & 1 &   &   & 1 &           \\
-   &   &   & 5 &   &   & {6\\ ~\\ ~\\ 9}
                                &   &   & \SetCell[c=1]{h}{8\\ ~\\ 10} 
                                            &       \\
-   &   &   & 6 &   &   & 7 &   &   & 7 &   &       \\
-   &   &   & 7 & 1 &   & 8 &   &   & 9 &   &       \\
-   & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & - & 3 &   &       \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]